# If input() returns a string, why doesn't print() display the quotation marks?

Tags: python-3.x, string, input, quotes

I'm having trouble understanding the following:

According to my book, unless otherwise specified, `input` will return a `string` type. If a `string` is printed wouldn't you expect the quotes to be included in the result? Is this just how `print()` is designed to work, if so why?

Example problem:

```
x = input() # user enters 5.5

print(x) # i expect '5.5' to be printed, instead 5.5 is printed
```

Wouldn't it be better to print the variable `x` for exactly what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you *use* quotes to create a literal string; quotes are not part of the string value itself. If you want to see the quotes, ask Python for the [representation of your string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), i.e.

```
print(repr(x))
```

Comment: Just be aware that `repr` does more than just put the quotes around the string.

Comment: @MarkRansom True, but it's the closest thing that will show you the how the string would have been constructed if it was a string literal.